# Qunit test property exists in object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I am using `Qunit` testing engine in JavaScript and I need to check if a property exists in an object.

Here is my setup:

```
 var tests = [
    {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        expected: {}
    },
    {
        foo: '',
        bar: '',
        expected: //I need to expect foo and bar properties to exist
    }
 ]

 for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    assert.deepEqual(validate_foo(tests[i]), tests[i].expected);
 }
```

The function `validate_foo()` either will return an empty object `{}` on success, or an object with the properties of each error. For example, `validate_foo()` expectes `foo` to equal `foo` and `bar` to equal `bar`. So in the second test, the result is:

```
{
    foo: 'foo does not equal foo',
    bar: 'bar does not equal bar'
}
```

How do I write a test to accomblish this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have totally missed the point, but assuming you are testing the validate_foo function, isn't this all you need to do?

```
var tests = [
    {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        expected: {}
    },
    {
        foo: '',
        bar: '',
        expected: {foo: 'foo does not equal foo',
                   bar: 'bar does not equal bar'}
    }
 ]

 for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    assert.deepEqual(validate_foo(tests[i]), tests[i].expected);
 }
```

...and if that's not the test you want then can you clarify what specifically you are trying to test in this case?